# Django - Set value for ajax request in all template files

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-templates

I have a website that uses ajax content loading for page contents. For all pages I check request that is ajax or not:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts': posts,
                                        'base_theme': 'ajax_base.html',
                                        })
else:
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts': posts,
                                        'base_theme': 'base.html'
                                        })
```

I have to set base_theme in all actions and I have to again set in template:

```
{% extends base_theme %}
```

How i can set global value for request in somewhere that chacks automaticlly request and set value for it. something like this:

```
if request.is_ajax():
    TEMPLATE_BASE = 'ajax_base.html'
else:
    TEMPLATE_BASE = 'base.html'
```

and after this i set render parameter normally:

```
return render(request, 'home.html', {'posts': posts})
```

and in `home.html`  file I want this:

```
{% extends TEMPLATE_BASE %}
```

Can I do this?
Where and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the `myapp/context_processors.py` file with this two-line function:

```
def template_base(request):
    template = 'ajax_base.html' if request.is_ajax() else 'base.html'
    return {'TEMPLATE_BASE': template}
```

And add this [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) to the `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    "myapp.context_processors.template_base",
)
```

Now you can write `{% extends TEMPLATE_BASE %}` in your templates.

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like exactly the sort of thing that a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) would be good for.

Comment: May give me an example?